# Detecting end of epoch in TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

How can one detect the end of one epoch (i.e completion of one full sweep through a dataset) in TF Object Detection API ? This might be useful to do some book-keeping or some internal processing (i.e resetting some weights) in the custom detection model

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement [tf.estimator.SessionRunHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/SessionRunHook)

To do this you need to edit model_lib.py at [tf.estimator.TrainSpec](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/febaae9a1bbbe1befac244715ed272558f19e8f0/research/object_detection/model_lib.py#L740) by adding the hook parameter, or create your own training file and override train_spec before you pass it to tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate .

Example of using ProfilerHook added to Tensorflow Object Detection API:
(should be similar for SessionRunHook)

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=model_dir, save_checkpoints_steps=save_checkpoints_steps,
                            save_checkpoints_secs=save_checkpoints_secs, keep_checkpoint_max=keep_checkpoint_max,
                            log_step_count_steps=log_step_count_steps)

train_and_eval_dict = model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs(
      run_config=config,
      hparams=model_hparams.create_hparams(hparams_overrides),
      pipeline_config_path=pipeline_config_path,
      config_override = cfg_override,
      train_steps=num_train_steps,
      sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=sample_1_of_n_eval_examples,
      sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples=sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples,
      save_final_config=save_final_config)

estimator = train_and_eval_dict['estimator']
train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['train_input_fn']
eval_input_fns = train_and_eval_dict['eval_input_fns']
eval_on_train_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['eval_on_train_input_fn']
predict_input_fn = train_and_eval_dict['predict_input_fn']
train_steps = train_and_eval_dict['train_steps']

train_spec, eval_specs = model_lib.create_train_and_eval_specs(
  train_input_fn,
  eval_input_fns,
  eval_on_train_input_fn,
  predict_input_fn,
  train_steps,
  eval_on_train_data=False)

profile_hook = tf.train.ProfilerHook(save_steps=profiler_save_step, save_secs=None, output_dir=profiler_output_dir, 
                                     show_dataflow=True, show_memory=True)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn
                                    ,max_steps=train_steps
                                    ,hooks=[profile_hook])

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
```